# Accessibility sequence is not proper when i pressing tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a tab Accessibility issue.

When I press tab it goes to cabana then month > sign and current date and so on. I'm facing an issue where it is skipping the current date. I'm using react date calendar.

I'm passing one index value.

```
    openDatePicker = () => {
        this.props.isKeyboardNavigationAllowed && this._datepicker && 
        this._datepicker.setOpen(true);
        if (this.props.setCarProdState) this.props.setCarProdState();
        setTimeout(() => {
          const reactDatepickerNavigation = document.querySelector(
            '.react-datepicker-popper .react-datepicker__navigation',
          );
          reactDatepickerNavigation && 
        reactDatepickerNavigation.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1');
        }, 0);
         };
setDatePickerPreSelection = (date) => this._datepicker && 
this._datepicker.setPreSelection(date);


    render() {
        try {
          let openToDate;
          const validOn = this.calendarSettings.validOnRange || 
    this.calendarSettings.validOn || [];
          const { blockJumpToActiveDate, dateOnMonthChange } = 
   this.state,
            localObj = getMainObject() || getLoggedInUser(),
            highlightDates = this.props.highlightDates && 
   this.props.highlightDates.find((item) => item['active-dates']);
          if (localObj && localObj.tenantID && 
   localObj.tenantID.toLowerCase() === UIConfig.ymcB2CTenant) {
            if (highlightDates && highlightDates['active-dates'].length > 
    0) {
              this.props.highlightDates.forEach((item) => {
                if (blockJumpToActiveDate && item['active-dates'] && 
    item['active-dates'].length > 0) {
                  openToDate = item['active-dates'][0];
                }
                if (blockJumpToActiveDate && dateOnMonthChange) {
                  openToDate = dateOnMonthChange;
                }
              });
            } else if (blockJumpToActiveDate && dateOnMonthChange) {
              openToDate = dateOnMonthChange;
            } else {
              openToDate = momentTimezone();
            }
          }
          return (
            <div>
              <span aria-live="assertive" id="selectedDateId" 
    className="sr-only"></span>
              <DatePicker
                ref={(dp) => (this._datepicker = dp)}
                locale="en-gb"
                fixedHeight={this.props.fixedHeight || false}
                selected={this.props.isDynamicPricingProd && 
    this.props.carProdsClicked ? '' : this.state.startDate}
                inline={
                  this.props.isDynamicPricingProd && 
    this.props.carProdsClicked
                    ? true
                    : this.props.inlineDisable
                    ? false
                    : true
                }
                monthsShown={this.props.dispMonths}
                minDate={this.includeDates & validOn && validOn.length 
    === 0 ? this.includeDates[0] : this.props.minDate}
                maxDate={
                  this.includeDates & validOn && validOn.length === 0
                    ? this.includeDates[this.includeDates.length - 1]
                    : this.props.maxDate
                }
                popperPlacement={this.props.popperPlacement ? 
    this.props.popperPlacement : ''}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                tabIndex={this.props.inlineDisable ? 0 : 1}
                dateFormat={this.props.dateFormat ? this.props.dateFormat :    ''}
                placeholderText={this.props.placeholderText ? 
    this.props.placeholderText : ''}
                onBlur={this.props.onBlurCustom && ((e) => 
    this.props.onBlurCustom(e, this.props.name, this.props.data))}
                filterDate={this.props.filterDate}
                openToDate={openToDate || this.props.openToDate}
                excludeDates={this.excludeDates}
                includeDates={validOn && validOn.length === 0 && 
    this.includeDates}
                calendarClassName={this.calendarSettings.calendarTooltip 
    ? 'date-picker-tooltip-on' : ''}
                highlightDates={this.props.highlightDates}
                onMonthChange={this.datePickerMonthChange}
                shouldCloseOnSelect={!this.props.disableCloseOnSelect}
                onClickOutside={this.props.onClickOutsideCustom && ((e) 
    => this.props.onClickOutsideCustom(e))}
                onFocus={this.props.isKeyboardNavigationAllowed && ((e) 
    => this.setFocusOnSelectedDate(e))}
                onKeyDown={this.props.isKeyboardNavigationAllowed && ((e) 
    => this.handleDatePickerKeyDown(e))}
              >
                {this.renderToolTip(this.state.startDate)}
              </DatePicker>
            </div>
          );
        } catch (err) {
          return logComponentRenderingError(err, 'Calendar');
        }
      }
    }
```

[image: image of calendar showing issue]

Comment: **tabIndex={this.props.inlineDisable ? 0 : 1}**  here I am passing index value  **reactDatepickerNavigation && reactDatepickerNavigation.setAttribute('tabindex', 
    '-1');**  this.props.inlineDisable  this is nothing i m just checking another component value